# Multiple assignment in an Object Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following Coffeescript code

```
module.exports = QuickEditor =
  quickEditorView : null
  panel : null
  subscriptions : null
  searcher : null

  activate: (state) -> 
  ...
```

That I'm trying to clean up a bit. I know coffeescript has a multiple assignment operator like

```
[cow, duck] = ["moo", "quack"]
```

But trying to do the following:

```
module.exports = QuickEditor =
  [quickEditorView, panel, subscriptions, searcher] : []

  activate: (state) -> 
  ...
```

Throws an error. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `[a,b] = array` doesn't actually produce an array, it is just a convenient notation for unpacking an array into some variables; similarly for `{a,b} = obj`. I think the best you can do is use a for-loop to set those properties.

Comment: Yeah I'm not trying to create an array, I'm simply trying to assign multiple variables to null at the same time.

Comment: Not really, you're trying to assign multiple *properties* at one time. Destructured assignment is more about unpacking data structures into variables than building objects.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "clean up" and what you're trying to accomplish with destructuring (-ed?) assignment.

If you wish your code to be concise and clear, you can't get much better than the first block. IMO, for four nulls, it's best to simply be explicit. Any more abstraction hurts legibility more than it helps.

If you want to save every last character for golf purposes, you could assign `a=null` or something. That saves you 12-7=5 characters.

If you were looking at a great many properties (hundreds or more) and you wanted to express the idea of "set **all the things** to null", you could do something like this:

```
  quickEditor[p] = null for p in 'quickEditorView panel subscriptions searcher bippity boppity boo veni vidi vici'.split(' ')
```

But I'd still probably prefer the explicit approach.